# Asterisk in Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, asterisk, sip, pjsip

Question?

I know there are restrictions for telecommunication service of instances within GCE.  I am clear there will be no direct connection to a PSTN but does this apply to SIP Provider Connectivity.  The SIP Provider will deliver telephone services and unified communications thru the SIP-based IP PBX on GCE.  Is this acceptable based on the GCP Restrictions?

Comment: If in doubt about the limitations in the ToS regarding telephony services, I'd recommend reaching out to Google Sales to discuss your use-case. Advice given on Stackoverflow is likely going to be wrong/inaccurate.

Answer (score 4):

We run several asterisk instances on GCP managing hundres of calls and it work fine. They must be installed on vm instances that are not shared (the free and/or small ones). The smaller we have is a 4 CPU and 4 GB installed on Centos 7 image.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk is realtime soft. That mean it should have GRANTED cpu every 50-100ms or so.

No,it will not work in Google cloud. Also will not work correctly in many virtualization environment without granted cpu access.

Sure you can try, but more then likly you will have gaps in sound.

Comment: Interesting answer, so you are writing the vCPU does not carry out the instructions or function of Asterisk?

Comment: Only if it not grant enough CPU time every 50ms.

Comment: This is going to be a challenge within this environment and need to continue my ongoing posts communication within the Asterisk Development Forum.  Wondering is this an universal setting independent of the selected Operating System selected to symbiotically work with Asterisk 13.20.0-rc2 update to follow 

Comment: This answer is likely based on incorrect assumptions. In GCE, only the shared machines types like f1-micro share CPU resources. The "normal" instances do not share a core -> your guest is always "granted" CPU.

Comment: I am sorry, you are wrong. micro always not work. other types sometimes works sometimes not.  High cost instances most of time works ok, but still not granted.

Comment: @arheops how are you defining high-cost instances?  Is this a general characteristic to consider from all cloud service providers?

Comment: More cpu power = less chance at any single moment you not got cpu for call and hear gap in sound. It related to number of calls and instance class. You have test it for your load if you really want use VPS.

Comment: @arheops interesting you write there will be a need for cpu power, received this reply "reviewed the instance metrics and noted a spike on CPU and Network usage' this after placing this call.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J8H2leO-0nk

Comment: then the instance had no space to log, there are no log files to look at.  Installed was mariadb, odbc, email to receive error messags plus logs and the only way to enter the cloud pbx was to stop and start it.  The plan is to grant maximum cpu time, prepare for storage of telephone information and sip trunking.